# Prisma migration fail with supabase

Tags: postgresql, prisma, supabase

I'm trying to generate some migrations using Prisma. 
I'm using Supabase which is using Postgres under the hood. 
Also, I tried to run the following command with the local emulator and with the "real project".

When I run `prisma db push` it's working, so the communication between prisma and supabase can be established.
But when I try to run `prisma migrate dev` I get the following error

```
Error: db error: ERROR: no such database: prisma_migrate_shadow_db_b2ce3e4e-c5ef-41f6-830f-2203a082f1db
   0: sql_migration_connector::flavour::postgres::sql_schema_from_migration_history
             at migration-engine/connectors/sql-migration-connector/src/flavour/postgres.rs:367
   1: migration_core::api::DevDiagnostic
             at migration-engine/core/src/api.rs:108
```

Supabase CLI : 0.15.3 
Prisma : 3.6.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I also asked this question on Prisma repo : https://github.com/prisma/prisma/issues/10575

The solution is to create a shadow database as mentionned in the documentation
https://www.prisma.io/docs/concepts/components/prisma-migrate/shadow-database#cloud-hosted-shadow-databases-must-be-created-manually

Comment: Were you able to do this with supabase? I don't see where in the UI I can create a 2nd database.

Comment: No, I did it with Docker by spawning a 2nd instance of a Postgresql DB

Comment: What if I can't run Docker locally? How should I do this in Supabase?

Comment: @stratis See my comment about supabase.

Comment: ok thnx! Could you plz provide an  example too?

Answer (score 0):

1. Prisma
   Prisma will try to drop the db during the migration and SupaBase doesn't like that so Prisma requires you to make a "Shadow Database"

Prisma Docs: [Shadow Databases](https://www.prisma.io/docs/concepts/components/prisma-migrate/shadow-database#cloud-hosted-shadow-databases-must-be-created-manually)

2. SupaBase
   To create the shadow db and get its connection string you have to connect to the SupaBase db with psql, create a new database and modify your connection string to point to the new db. (because prisma IS allowed to delete this second db during migration)

SupaBase Docs: [Prisma (Shadow db)](https://supabase.com/docs/guides/integrations/prisma)

Answer (score 0):

## Environment

- Framework: Next JS
- ORM: Prisma
- DB: Supabase(Cloud)

## Problem

```
Error: db error: FATAL: bouncer config error
   0: migration_core::state::DevDiagnostic
             at migration-engine/core/src/state.rs:269
```

## Reason

1. According to Prisma [documentation](https://www.prisma.io/docs/concepts/components/prisma-migrate/shadow-database#cloud-hosted-shadow-databases-must-be-created-manually), the `prisma migrate` command requires second, temporary database called `Shadow Database` in order to detect problems such as [schema drift](https://www.prisma.io/docs/concepts/components/prisma-migrate/shadow-database#detecting-schema-drift).

   > Some development-focused commands for relational databases of Prisma
   > Migrate use a second, temporary database:
   >
   > - `prisma migrate dev`
   > - `prisma migrate reset`

   > The shadow database is created and deleted automatically* each time you run a development-focused command and is primarily used to detect problems such as schema drift.
2. Therefore, Supabase needs to create additional DB temporarily.
3. According to the same doc if you are using a `cloud-hosted database` for development, you need to create the [shadow database manually](https://www.prisma.io/docs/concepts/components/prisma-migrate/shadow-database#cloud-hosted-shadow-databases-must-be-created-manually).

## Solution

1. `create` another DB in Supabase Cloud.
2. `copy` newly created `Supabase Cloud URL`
3. `Add` new `SHADOW_DATABASE_URL` field in `.env`.
4. `paste` `Supabase Cloud URL` to `SHADOW_DATABASE_URL`
5. Add `shadowDatabaseUrl = env("SHADOW_DATABASE_URL")` in `schema.prisma`:

   ```js
   datasource db {
     provider          = "postgresql"
     url               = env("DATABASE_URL")
     shadowDatabaseUrl = env("SHADOW_DATABASE_URL")
   }
   ```
6. `save` files and run `npx prisma db migrate`